# Define upper bound type to allow arithmetic operations

Tags: scala

Is it possible to define a upper bound type that would allow the basic arithmetic operations in the function? Simply to make this work:

```
def a[T](t:T):T = {t*t}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no common super-type for all possible numeric types in Scala, so I would use the [Numeric](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric) trait. It isn't a type bound, but rather a type class where you can require an implicit `Numeric[A]` be available in scope. Implicits already exist in scope for all of Scala's numeric types.

```
def a[T](t: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = num.times(t, t)
```

Or

```
def a[T: Numeric](t: T): T = implicitly[Numeric[T]].times(t, t)
```

Comment: It works but is very cumbersome. Is there really no cleaner solution than this for such a typical problem? Is it deliberate from the Scala core team to not propose a Numeric type class? With such a type class, one simply do `def a[T <: Numeric](t: T): T = t*t` ?

Comment: @Jivan `Numeric` _is_ a type class. `T <: Numeric` would mean that `T` is a subtype of `Numeric`. Unfortunately, it's a problem essentially inherited from Java, because Java's numeric types are split between primitives and objects. Scala could implement its own types, but then there might be issues with interoperability and optimization. If you don't like having to write out `num.times(t, t)`, then you can always `import scala.math.Numeric.Implicits._` and write `t * t` in one of the above examples.

Answer (score 1):

The Scala [spire](https://github.com/non/spire) library is awesome. It provides many types of numeric abstractions.

```
import spire.math._
import spire.implicits._

def negate[A: Integral](x: A) = -(42 * (x /~ 42) + x % 42)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also found a similar solution (that allows division, too)

```
import scala.math.Integral.Implicits._  

def a[T:Integral](t:T):T = t * t / t
```